# symbol keys missing on my keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, input-language

I installed LTS 14.04 and ever since some of my keys went missing. First, the dot symbol key is not working, so I have to use the dot key from the numeric keypad. Secondly, the right alt key is a shortcut for mute speaker volume although I deleted all multi media short cuts in the system settings/keyboard. Thirdly, on the 12.04 LTS version and with english language option selected I was able to type german characters while pressing the right Alt key + q,y,p for ä,ü,ö. This was very convenient, because I did not have to switch to German language. This feature does not work any longer, because the right Alt key is now mute speaker volume and I can't change it. I appreciate your help and thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You need to clarify your question a bit. Which feature(s) for controlling the keyboard behavior is it you need help with? Did you install a fresh 14.04, or did you upgrade from 12.04?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I´m pretty sure it was an upgrade from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS. I did not have to move any files and nothing was overwritten.  I solved the german characters issue, though. I had to look it up once more and changed to english international with dead keys and now I´m able to input the german umlauts like before. However, the dot key is still not working. Also, the quotation symbol key is not working properly. I have to hit the key twice for the symbol to appear on screen.

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer to address the issues you mentioned in the comment. Can you please edit your question, so it clearly focuses on those issues.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about *English (US, international with dead keys)*, that keyboard layout turns the quotation symbol key to a dead_diaeresis key for typing e.g. ë. To type the quotation symbol you need to press both `<AltGr>` and `<Shift>`.

The dot key should be unchanged, though.

You can see an overview of the currently selected keyboard layout by clicking the input source indicator in the menu and selecting *Keyboard Layout Chart*.